# Why is using pointer killing performance

Tags: c++, performance, inheritance, allocation

Let's say I have a class `Manager` that does some work, and then I have a `DistributedManager`, which inherits from `Manager` but reimplement some methods to use multithreading.

The code for using those would be

```
 Manager<T,W,P> manager(initargs);
 manager.compute(runargs);
```

or

```
 DistributedManager<T,W,P> manager(initargs, 4); // 4 is number of thread to use
 manager.compute(runargs);
```

then at some point I want the number of thread to use to me modifiable through the command like. So I make a `size_t nbthread = 1` which can be modifier by an option and I modify my code as folows:

```
Manager<T,W,P>* manager;
switch(nbthread)
{
    case 0:
    case 1:
        manager = new Manager<T,W,P>(initargs);
        break;
    default:
        manager = new DistributedManager<T,W,P>(initargs, nbthread);
        break;
}
manager->compute(runargs);
```

It compiles and works ... but I got crapy performances !

Using the first methode with `DistributedManager` and 4 threads I can run in 500ms, using the second methode the same computation runs in over 2000ms.

The allocation part should not be that long:

```
sizeof(Manager<T,W,P>) : 104
sizeof(DistributedManager<T,W,P>) : 128
```

What is going wrong ?

### Edit

benchmarking is done using

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
densityfieldptr->compute(particles, massfield, massthreshold, densityfunctor);
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
printf("computation time: %ld ms\n", std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count());
```

### Edit 2 : I'm stupid

The increass in time was about a factor 4 ... because the non multithreaded version was the one called. Using a pointer to base class made thoses methods where used!

`virtual` keyword could not be used to solve that as the methode is templated

I had to rethink my template pattern and everything worked as expected

Comment: Please don't call your classes `Manager` :|

Comment: Show the code and the benchmark harness.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Manager was just an exemple, my real classes are `AdaptiveDensity` and `DistributedAdaptiveDensity`

Comment: There is not enough information present to explain the performance difference.

Comment: What does this `Manager<T,W,P> manager(initargs, 4);` do if `Manager` is not distributed?

Comment: @Barry there was a tipo, editted

Comment: The code is not complete. This question cannot be answered.

Comment: Something is not seem right. if you repeat the test is it the same result?

Comment: Are you just creating the `Manager` and calling `compute` once? That part will be slower, but not by a huge amount.

Comment: the full code is unfortunately not public. Which part would you consider important ? Classes constructors ?

Comment: @SHR I repetead the test several (~20) times

Comment: You are correct that the pointer could not possibly be the cause.  So something else must be different and that is why people are asking to see the rest of the code.  You may need to use a code profiler to see what is really causing the trouble.

Comment: try to make the same without the real code.

Comment: What's with the hate towards managers, we call the guy who empties the trashcans a manager, too. :-)

Comment: The issue may be frequent dynamic memory allocations.  You should only allocate the items once.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with comments that say there is not enough information to say definitively what is happening, but I have a theory ([false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing)) which is too long for a comment, so this is a tentative answer.

The main difference between the two is the storage allocation

- DistributedManager manager(initargs, 4);  // automatic storage allocation
- manager = new DistributedManager(initargs, nbthread); // dynamic storage allocation

Automatic storage is implemented on the stack, dynamic storage on the heap.  You say so what?
Well the implementation of "new" doesn't guarantee allocation at a cache line boundary and multiple of cache lines.  I have had performance problems with that before, where an object on the heap is shared with another object that is accessed by another thread and at least one of them is modified (written to by the thread) - false sharing.  This causes that cache line to "ping-pong" back and forth between the cores where the threads are running.  It is not a logic bug, but it is a performance bug.  The compiler *may* be allocating on the stack in a way that prevents false sharing, or it may *just happen* to not be an issue there but it may not be guaranteed, change something in your program and you may see a problem with automatic storage also.  The only way to fix that is to use a custom allocator.

Comment: It's impossible to confirm without seeing the rest of the code, but  it's likely that most of the time spent in the program is spent in the `->compute()` method (which may be poorly implemented in the `DistributedManager`).  I doubt that dynamic memory allocation of the manager object is the culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

Using pointers can cause cache misses and branch miss predictions. But without a profiler you will only get guesses, not a solid answer.